# Multiple edit form on single page rails 4

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I am building a one page  flyer in rails 4. In that I need to edit multiple form in one single page. How can I achieve this?

I go through railscast 346 Wizard form but doesn't help me.

I need something as shown in image as I click on a "Done" information should save or updated.

Is it possible multiple submit button in one page with ajax/jquery.

[image]

Page can have multiple forms as shown in pic.

Answer (score 3):

Of course you can. Assuming you have a partial `_form.html.erb` containg sth in lines:

```
<%= form_for model, remote: true do |f| %>
  <%# your form here %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You can just take all the models you want to edit and iterate over them:

```
 <% models_to_edit.each do |model|%>
   <%= render 'form', model: model %>
 <% end %>
```

Since each form has its own submit button, pressing it will submit only the form it belongs to.

Comment: What about each cancel/Done button......How can i achieve individual submission ..hope you clear what i try to say

Comment: Submit buttons submit only the form it is embedded in and ignores the other forms.

Comment: Can you plz  make it more clear perhaps with sample code in your answer?

Comment: @Anish - I've updated the answer, could you say what isn't too clear?

Comment: this line gets the `_form.html.erb` file, builds it and place it in the view. Since the partial is using `model` variable, it needs to be passed form the main view with `model: model`

Comment: One quick question where do i put <% models_to_edit.each do |model|%>
   <%= render 'form', model: model %>
 <% end %> i mean which view?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52514/discussion-between-broisatse-and-anish)

Comment: I think with this solution all the input elements will have the same id. So if you use `f.label(:title)` clicking on the title label will take you to the title text input in the first form on the page, not the form you are in.